# which is better, store formatted values, or format it when requested

Tags: mysql, sql

Values like phone, should we store it already formatted, or format it when requested?
Which is better for performance?

At countries like brazil we have the code 55, city code like 11, but phone numbers we have with 5 or 4 digits plus 4 digits, like:
+55 (11) 9999-9999 or +55 (21) 9999-9999, storing unformatted value, few countries, you have country code with 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits, it will become hard to format when requested, because that!
Storing formatted, i will use so much more space stored, INT < VARCHAR.
But by processing, we just throw the value to display.
If i store it like number, i have to have a lot of IFs to identify the country and the format, taking low space but a high processing time.

Sorry my english.

Comment: That depends, if your application will be used globally then you must keep the raw values and format when required with obviously a little performance hit. Otherwise you may keep it in one format.

Comment: At countries like brazil we have the code 55

Comment: i always think you should do it in presentation

Comment: If you have to determine the country or city code from the database side, you should store them in separate fields.  Otherwise you will have to parse each string to figure out how to handle it, and may very well force your queries to do full table scans when they wouldn't otherwise have to...

Answer (score 6):

Well, consider that a typical modern desktop computer can do 6 or 7 billion calculations per second.

Data should be stored in the best format for doing the things you do in a database:  searching, sorting, comparing.    Phone numbers can potentially come in from UIs in different formats (e.g. "(800) 555-1212", "800-555-1212"  "800 555-1212",  "8005551212").  Allowing different functionality like matching would pretty much dictate that the format be stripped before storing to the database, and then prettied up when it is displayed.

The processor overhead of formatting a phone number is trivial:  perhaps 40 or 50 processor cycles.   That would be something far short of a microsecond, on an i5, for instance.

So I would vote for:  store raw, display pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Since formatting is a display concern independent of data storage, and because the same piece of data may be formatted differently based on the environment, you should store unformatted data in the database, and format it as appropriate in your application.

You may build an application where the same data could be viewed from different locales. The same amount of money, point in time, or a number may need to be formatted differently for different users, depending on where they are coming from. Your data model should (of which MySQL is a big part) should not deal with formatting at all, otherwise the presentation layer would need to convert the data from one format to another. This is suboptimal, and may lead to maintainability nightmares. That is why you should strive to store the data in a way that is independent of the presentation formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I store phone numbers as digits only. This sabers space in the database. Formats can change. Also, when writing code being concise and reusing code its something to strive for.
This function tales up less space than less than 100 or so formatted phone numbers in a database table.

```
    function format_phone($phone = '', $convert = false, $trim = true){
        // If we have not entered a phone number just return empty
        if (empty($phone)) {
            return '';
        }

        // Strip out any extra characters that we do not need only keep letters and numbers
        $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Za-z]/", "", $phone);

        // Do we want to convert phone numbers with letters to their number equivalent?
        // Samples are: 1-800-TERMINIX, 1-800-FLOWERS, 1-800-Petmeds
        if ($convert == true) {
            $replace = array('2'=>array('a','b','c'),
                     '3'=>array('d','e','f'),
                         '4'=>array('g','h','i'),
                     '5'=>array('j','k','l'),
                                     '6'=>array('m','n','o'),
                     '7'=>array('p','q','r','s'),
                     '8'=>array('t','u','v'),
                     '9'=>array('w','x','y','z'));

            // Replace each letter with a number
            // Notice this is case insensitive with the str_ireplace instead of str_replace 
            foreach($replace as $digit=>$letters) {
                $phone = str_ireplace($letters, $digit, $phone);
            }
        }

        // If we have a number longer than 11 digits cut the string down to only 11
        // This is also only ran if we want to limit only to 11 characters
        if ($trim == true && strlen($phone)>11) {
            $phone = substr($phone, 0, 11);
        }                        

        // Perform phone number formatting here
        if (strlen($phone) == 7) {
            return preg_replace("/([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})/", "$1-$2", $phone);
        } elseif (strlen($phone) == 10) {
            return preg_replace("/([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})/", "($1) $2-$3", $phone);
        } elseif (strlen($phone) == 11) {
            return preg_replace("/([0-9a-zA-Z]{1})([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})/", "$1($2) $3-$4", $phone);
        }

        // Return original phone if not 7, 10 or 11 digits long
        return $phone; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to format data on report/display typically, can save space and can increase performance in some situations.

Ultimately I think it depends on how you're using the data.  If phone numbers aren't going to be used in analysis and are just detail info then storing a formatted string doesn't hurt much.

If you'll be performing any calculations using the field, definitely keep it in an appropriate datatype.  Name/Address/Phone/Zip are fields I often keep as strings with little consequence.

Answer (score 0):

## Format when requested!

Anyone with any modicum of formal academic database training will tell you this. Even better if this formatting happens at the database client, rather than in the database itself.